# Parallel polygons intersection detection

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, line-intersection

Is there an easy way of detecting the intersection of two concave polygons that have all of their sides either parallel or orthogonal to one another?

Comment: So all sides of both polygons run north/south or east/west?  I don't think you'll get anything easy.  By making the sides very small, you can fake a diagonal line, and make the polygons do whatever you want.  So now you've eliminated the only thing that could have helped you out.  The answer might change if there is a minimum side length and maximum polygon diameter, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of problems with rectilinear (isothetic) polygons was studied by Preparata and Shamos (for example - in the book Computational Geometry: An Introduction).

I think, you have to look at the **sweep line** algorithm